# Why can't print be assigned to foo in python 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Why does the python 2 code throw error on assigning `print` to `foo` whereas python 3 doesn't?

Python 2

```
>>> foo = print
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    foo = print
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python 3

```
>>> foo = print
```

Comment: print is a keyword in python 2, and a function in python 3. The duplicate has answers that explain this (even if the question is different)

Comment: `print` is a statement in Python 2, so just like you can't assign `for` you can't assign `print`